# limit of vector when norm goes to infinity

Tags: limits, normed-spaces

Consider a $x \in \mathbb{R}^p$ and $a \in \mathbb{R}^p$ be a fixed vector. If $| \cdot|$ is the Euclidean norm, what can we say about:

$\lim_{|x| \to \infty} \dfrac{a^T x}{|x|}$.

My intuition says that the limit will be finite, since $|x|$ should increase at a faster rate than the linear combination of the components of $x$, but I am not able to show it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The limit as written does not exist.  In particular, there is no one value that works as the limit.  For example: note that if we take $x(t) = ta$, then we have
$$
\lim_{t \to \infty} \frac{a^Tx(t)}{|x(t)|} = |a|
$$
On the other hand, if we take $x(t) = tb$ where $b$ is perpendicular to $a$, then we have
$$
\lim_{t \to \infty} \frac{a^Tx(t)}{|x(t)|} = 0
$$
However, we may indeed state (using the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality) that
$$
\limsup_{x \to \infty} \frac{a^Tx}{|x|} = |a|
$$

Comment: And if $p=1$, we still get different answers if we take $x(t) = ta$ and $x(t) = -ta$.

Comment: I did come up with the limsup argument. I guess I am more interested to know whether the limit can be $- \infty$? Can we find the $\liminf$?

Comment: It seems natural that the $\liminf$ should be $-|a|$.

Comment: Yep, that's right.  It can't be made to go to $-\infty$